# Latin Accents not working in sub-files

Tags: accents

I am working in a multi-file document and i have imported the [latin]{inputenc} package in the main document but it isn't working in the subfiles.

Main.tex

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\usepackage{titlesec} %Only for book
%\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge\it} %Only for book
\usepackage{subfiles}

\author{Yamil Saade}
\title{Caracterización de Laminados}

\begin{document}

    %\frontmatter
    \maketitle

    %\mainmatter

    \section{Introducción}
    \subfile{Sections/Introduction}


\end{document}
```

Subfile.tex

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

    Hoy en día natación

\end{document}
```

Result from the code Above ...

[image: Result]

Comment: Try using unicode for your files instead. Check if your subfile actually uses latin-1 too.

Comment: most editors will (and should) default to UTF-8 today not latin1 (iso-8859-1) make sure that all your files are UTF-8 encoded and then change `[latin1]` to `[utf8]`  the subfiles showing accented A are already in UTF-8 but display incorrectly as you have declared latin1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem is not related to the `subfiles` package,** but is a mismatch between the specified encoding, `latin1`, and the actually used one, `utf8`. Consider the following file:

```
% test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % Sets the expected encoding to Latin1
\begin{document}
Hoy en día natación % Actually uses UTF8
\end{document}
```

where the accented letters are stored in UTF-8 encoding. Under Linux, you can use the `file` command to check the encoding actually used:

```
$ file test.tex
test.tex: LaTeX 2e document, UTF-8 Unicode text
```

For windows, see [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13464816/7032505) on how to check and to change the encoding using `notepad`.

Running LaTeX on `test.tex` results in three errors:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.4 Hoy en día natació
                        n
? 
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\maththreesuperior ->{^3}

l.4 Hoy en día natació
                        n
? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.5 \end{document}
```

If you (or your TeX system) skip these errors, you will get the following output:

[image]

### Solution

Make sure that all your TeX files use the same character encoding. Nowadays UTF-8 is the standard, but Latin1 is also fine. Just make sure that you use the same encoding everywhere. Depending on your choice, use either

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

or

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Running LaTeX on the file

```
% test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Sets expected encoding to UTF8
\begin{document}
Hoy en día natación % Actually uses UTF8
\end{document}
```

gives no errors and results in the output

[image]